# How to convert a double to NSInteger?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, numbers

Very simple question here.  I have a double that I wish to convert back to a NSInteger, truncating to the units place.  How would I do that?

Comment: any reason you want a NSInteger instead of a NSNumber? also do you want rounding or just a straight chop off?

Comment: Now that I think about it, it'd be nice to have it round up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Truncation is an implicit conversion:

```
NSInteger theInteger = theDouble;
```

That's assuming you're not checking the value is within NSInteger's range. If you want to do that, you'll have to add some branching:

```
NSInteger theInteger = 0;
if (theDouble > NSIntegerMax) {
    // ...
} else if (theDouble < NSIntegerMin) {
    // ...
} else {
    theInteger = theDouble;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks.  Added bonus of checking for range, except I don't have to worry about that for my use.  Thanks again!

Comment: You mentioned rounding up in a comment. Use `ceil(theDouble)` for rounding up, `floor(theDouble)` for rounding down. Remember that for negative numbers, rounding up is rounding toward zero, and rounding down is rounding toward negative infinity.

Comment: +1: ahh i made a simple rounding function below..didn't remember ceil and floor for doubles. much better and precise answer

Comment: Thank you for the rounding answer.

Answer (score 5):

NSInteger is a typedef for a C type. So you can just do:

```
double originalNumber;
NSInteger integerNumber = (NSInteger)originalNumber;
```

Which, per the C spec, will truncate originalNumber.

Comment: Looks like you got the same answer at the same time. :)

Comment: Yes, but Jonathan covered range, so definitely deserves the tick.

Answer (score 1):

but anyway, assuming you want no rounding,  i believe this should work simply

```
double myDouble = 10.4223;
NSInteger myInt = myDouble;
```

edit for rounding: (i'm sure theres a much simpler (and precise) way to do this.. (this also doesn't account for negative numbers or maximum boundaries)

```
double myDecimal = myDouble - myInt;
if(myDecimal < 0.50)
{
//do nothing
}
else
{
myInt = myInt + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NSInteger is a typedef, it's the same as using an int. Just assign the value like:

`double d;

NSInteger i = d;`

Answer (score 0):

JesseNaugher mentions rounding and I note the OP needs were met with a simple truncate, but in the spirit of full generalisation it's worth remembering the simple trick of adding 0.5 to the double before invoking floor() to achieve rounding. Extending Jonathan Grynspan's comment: `NSInteger myInt = floor(myDouble + 0.5);` i.e., rounding up in *absolute* terms. If rounding 'up' means rounding away from zero a more convoluted approach is needed: `NSInteger myInt = floor( myDouble + (myDouble < 0.0 ? -0.5 : 0.5) );`